# How to insert undefined value as null for pg node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Is there a better method of inserting a variable that is undefined as null using pg

```
const pg = require('pg');
a = a? a: null  // hope to remove this line
b = b? b: null  // hope to remove this line
c = c? c: null  // hope to remove this line

client.query('INSERT INTO abc(a,b,c) VALUES($1,$2,$3)', [a,b,c], function(err, result) { 
  //do something here
})
```

so that don't have to check every variable and substitute "" for undefined before

Comment: The code shown doesn't use `null` at all. Empty strings aren't null.

Comment: do you realise this code would replace the number `0` and the boolean `false` with `''` as well?

Comment: if you're hoping to remove the 3 lines then will this work? `[ a || null, b || null, c || null]`

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) does it automatically, both `undefined` and `null` are formatted as `null`.

Comment: thanks pg-promise seems to be pretty cool, can i check how does pg-promise handle partial updates? if u have SQL statement like UPDATE users SET name=$1, age = $2 WHERE id = $3   and values being ['a', undefined, 'id1'] does pg-promise update age column with null? or do a partial update by ignoring age?

Answer (score 2):

you can define a undefined variable using || operator.
Ex

```
var a ;
var b = a || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value with Boolean like

```
let test = null;
let b = `test is ${Boolean(test) == false ? "null" : ",'" + test + "'"}`;
```